# SQL Group by sex then age

Tags: group-by

I have a Patients table as below:

**Patients**

```
Name       Gender   DOB
Student A    M      03-mar-2001 
Student B    F      08-dec-1985 
Student C    F      12-sep-1990 
Student D    M      20-may-1981
```

I would like to have a SQL statement to display the result as below:

```
Gender  0-19  20-29  30-39
M         1     0      1 
F         0     2      0
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check below query

```
CREATE TABLE #t1 (NAME VARCHAR(100),Gender VARCHAR(10),DOB DATE)

INSERT INTO #t1(NAME,Gender,DOB) VALUES('Student A','M','03-mar-2001')
INSERT INTO #t1(NAME,Gender,DOB) VALUES('Student B','F','08-dec-1985')
INSERT INTO #t1(NAME,Gender,DOB) VALUES('Student C','F','12-sep-1990')
INSERT INTO #t1(NAME,Gender,DOB) VALUES('Student D','M','20-may-1981')

SELECT Gender , SUM(CASE WHEN  DATEDIFF(yy,DOB,GETDATE()) BETWEEN 0 AND
20 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  [0-19],
SUM(CASE WHEN  DATEDIFF(yy,DOB,GETDATE()) BETWEEN 21 AND 30 
THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [20-29],
SUM(CASE WHEN  DATEDIFF(yy,DOB,GETDATE()) BETWEEN 31 AND 40 
THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [30-39]
FROM #t1
GROUP BY Gender
```